# Using AsyncTask to Update UI (Layout dynamically)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-asynctask

The following code is currently run in the onCreate() of my main. I am just testing at the moment. I have been trying to get this to be done in an AsyncTask, as the goal is to be able to update these dynamically later on but can't seem to find out how to do that. I was wondering if anyone had some insight. Thank you!

```
LinearLayout ObjectLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutObjects);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.height = 140;
    params.width = 140;
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        btn.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
        btn.setTextSize(14);
        btn.setText("MyButton");
        btn.setTextColor(color.Yellow);
        // Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/add_page");
        // //
        // btn.setBackgroundDrawable(image);

        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.add_page));
        // btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

        ObjectLayout.addView(btn);

    }




private class GetDataTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Simulates a background job.

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            publishProgress(btn2);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void publishProgress(Button btn2) {
        btn2.setLayoutParams(params2);
        btn2.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
        btn2.setTextSize(14);
        btn2.setText("MyButton yo yo yo ");
        btn2.setTextColor(color.Yellow);

        btn2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.add_page));
        ObjectLayout2.addView(btn2);
        // Process width and height
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // Do some stuff here

        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.

    }
}
```

This code here is what I have as my async and defined the layouts and button creation as instance in mainactivity, just to test and understand this but I am getting errors, I have been manipulating it around but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar(inflate/add around 80-120 custom views at once into a scrollable layout), and my AsyncTask structure was something like this:

First, you need to pass your `Context` and `LinearLayout` to your AsyncTask. Just use a custom constructor for this.

`onPreExecute()`: Show a progress dialog, or something to show "busy".

`doInBackground()` : Create the buttons in your loop just like you are, but don't more than that on that thread. The creation/inflation part is what takes most of the time, so no worries. At the end of each loop cycle, `publishProgress(btn)`.

`onProgressUpdate()`: Set the button(passed from above) up the way you like(text/padding/etc), and add it to the layout.

`onPostExecute()`: Dismiss your dialog.

A note, using one thread to inflate and one to lay out doesn't increase speed much. Mine went from about 2.5 seconds without an AsyncTask to just over 2 with. However, this way it gives a clear progress dialog instead of the UI just hanging while it inflates all the views. It may not be much faster, but it *feels* much more responsive, and that's what really matters.

**EDIT:** 
For an example of a custom constructor, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885350/how-to-pass-different-objects-as-a-parameter-to-asyctask). It also shows how you can skip the constructor and pass it straight to the `doInBackground()` method. Either way works   just fine.

Comment: "First, you need to pass your Context and LinearLayout to your AsyncTask. Just use a custom constructor for this." What exactly would that look like, sorry for the dumb question, just a little confused.

Comment: I added more code as to the async I was gonna go about a custom constructor after I got this testing to work and understood it a little better, just curious if you could take a look see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are normally for long background operations.  So unless you want your buttons to be updated after such a task, I'm not sure why you would want to use one?

However, if that is indeed your purpose, then you would execute whatever tasks/code you need in the doInBackground() function of your AsyncTask.  When that is completed, the onPostExecute() function of the AsyncTask is where you will update your UI accordingly.

Perhaps you could include a little more detail as to the nature of your 'loading dynamically' requirements so that the community can provide a more specific answer for you.

Comment: If you need more code let me know but, essentially think of that button as calling in up to as many as 100 or 200 that are going to be removed and added in an out of that layout which is a scrollable one. It will be a much longer operation when that code is finalized. I am using also a pull down to refresh to update these that's why I figured async method would be appropriate. The above action is essentially the only example of what needs to be done there that I was testing. Thank you for the insight so far on that though, sorry if I'm not being descriptive enough just let me know.